# How to select a block of text containing a string by a regex?

Tags: regex

Given the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit.

Phasellus id 
tristique est.

Mauris eget massa leo.
Pellentesque egestas 
ante vitae finibus luctus. 

Nam tristique metus 
nec semper semper.
```

Is it possible to match the 2 blocks containing the string `tristique` via a regular expression?

So these would be the 2 matches:

```
Phasellus id 
tristique est.

Nam tristique metus 
nec semper semper.
```

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 5):

You could try the below regex.

```
(?s)\b(?:(?!\n\n).)*?\btristique\b(?:(?!\n\n).)*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP1kI0/4)

`(?:(?!\n\n).)*` matches any character but not of `\n\n`, zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

The reasonable way consists to split the string by paragraph (`\n\n+`) and after to find the paragraphs with "tristique". It may be the fastest way.

Javascript example:

```
var result = text.split(/^\n+|\n\n+/).filter(function (elt) {
    return /\btristique\b/.test(elt);
});
```

To do the same task in one shot, and to prevent a lot of backtracking, you need to use advanced regex features that aren't available in javascript. An example with PHP:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~^
# non-empty lines without the target word
(?:
    (?=\N) #check if there is one character
    # content without the target word
    [^t\n]*+ #all until a "t" or a newline
    (?: \Bt+[^t\n]* | t+(?!ristique\b)[^t\n]* )*+ #when a "t" is met
    \n #a newline
)*+

# characters until the target word
[^t\n]*+
(?: \Bt+[^t\n]* | t+(?!ristique\b)[^t\n]* )*+
(*SKIP) # if the target word doesn't follow then skip the substring

tristique  # target: note that word boundaries are implicit
\N*        # trailing characters
(?:\n\N+)* # following non empty lines
~mx
EOD;

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
// do what you have to do
}
```